# ler arquivos pdf com php diretamente no browser

Tags: php

Colegas. É possível abrir um arquivo PDF diretamente dentro do navegador? Tentei o file_get_contents() e o fopen(), mas ele abriu de decodificado. Então tentei dessa forma, mas ele abriu no browser inteiro:

```
$arquivo='0eb178d150b82f5536588fbfea5fa7bd.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="0eb178d150b82f5536588fbfea5fa7bd.pdf"');
 @readfile($arquivo);
```

Comment: A primeira questão é: você mandou o mime-type correto nos headers? Como você já tem um tempo de site, deve saber que se postar seu código, fica mais fácil de localizarmos os possíveis problemas.

Comment: Olá Bacco, tem razão, esqueci de colocar o código. Editei a minha dúvida.

Comment: Só não acho certo darem ponto negativo antes de nos manifestarmos, pois isso é caráter de urgência e fechando o tópico, atrasará quem realmente precisa de ajuda. O certo é esperarem se quem postou a dúvida irá acatar o questionamento do colega antes de darem pontos negativos.

Comment: Experimente sem a @ pra ver se dá algum erro. E não se preocupe com negativo, pois não fecha a questão. Aliás, se vc deixasse sem o código, seria normal fecharem como "não estar clara", mas isso é diferente de negativo.

Comment: Certo Bacco. O problema é que ele abre no browser inteiro e só preciso abrir dentro de uma div...

Comment: Bom, no ultimo edit já mudou a questão completamente. Se vc quer que façam download, troque o application/pdf por application/octet-stream, se quer abrir numa div não dá, aí só com um IFRAME ou nova janela. No IFRAME nem sei se dá, pra falar a verdade.

Comment: Alterei, mas ele pede para alterar...

Comment: Entendi...vou tentar aqui com o iframe...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file = './path/to/the.pdf';
$filename = 'Custom file name for the.pdf'; /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
?>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/

Código funcionando http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/wesley/pdf_in_browser/pdf.php

Comment: Desculpe, só depois de responder, vi que precisa exibir dentro da dIv. Neste caso o iframe servirá.